# Condition number of Hessian matrix when Hessian is singular

Tags: reference-request, optimization, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

In gradient descent on a quadratic problem,

$$\min _{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\frac12 \langle Hx, x \rangle + \langle b, x \rangle + c \qquad H \text{ symmetric, positive semi-definite}\quad b \in \operatorname{Range}(H)$$

the condition number of the Hessian, $\kappa(H)$, is related to the convergence rate via $\frac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa + 1}$. Suppose $H$ is singular and positive semi-definite. Then $\kappa(H)$, depending on the definition of $\kappa$, might be infinite. But I think in this case I should be concerned only with $\tilde{\kappa}(H) = \frac{\lambda_1(H)}{\lambda_k(H)}$, where $\lambda_k$ is the largest non-zero eigenvalue of $A$. ($k = \operatorname{Rank}(H)$). And I shouldn't worry about the nullspace of $H$.

My logic is: since $b \in \operatorname{Range}(A) = \operatorname{Nullspace}(A)^\perp$, I can really treat this problem as optimization in $\operatorname{Range}(A) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $A|_{\operatorname{Range}(A)}$ is nonsingular, right? Because no component of $x_k - x_{k-1}$ along $\operatorname{Nullspace}(A)$ will either affect the objective function nor will it ever show up in the gradient $Ax + b \in \operatorname{Range}(A)$, so it should never show up in gradient descent in the first place (when we're dealing with a quadratic with a min)?

Now suppose I'm right about the above. Suppose we're in a more complicated problem (say a machine learning problem), and we're looking at $\kappa(H)$ (which now depends on $x$) as a signal for how bad our optimization problem is. (We hope it indicates whether we'll encounter narrow valleys, etc.) Why might or might not I be justified in considering the $\tilde{\kappa}(H)$ as opposed to $\kappa(H)$, when the latter is possibly infinite?

Some ideas:

- In a general optimization problem, it's impossible to tell from merely local information whether we're justified in ignoring a certain subspace in our gradient search for an optimum.
- In practice, we'll be dealing with computer error and inexact quantities, so there really isn't much difference between problems where $H$ is non-invertible, and problems where it is very poorly conditioned.
- Some algorithms such as BFGS require the Hessian to be invertible to come up with their next step, so this is a problem.

What other considerations might I want to be aware of?

Comment: Two thoughts related to your 1st and 3rd bullet point: If the optimization problem is not purely quadratic, a single Hessian provides no information about the convergence rate. BFGS does not care about the Hessian. It will run as long as the search direction is not orthogonal to the difference in gradients.

Comment: @LinAlg Although the Hessian provides no bound on the convergence rate in general, is not the condition number of the Hessian used as a rough signal of the difficulty of an optimization problem in machine learning, for instance?